# How to query get only data with multi relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, database, api, relationship

I'm having a bit of a problem like this but haven't found a solution yet. Hope everyone can help, thank you very much!!!
I want to get only the required data of each table and return a json like this:

**I want this output**

```
"data" : [
    {
      {
          "id": 1,
          "user" : {
            "name" : "string"
          },
          "package" : {
            "name" : "string"
          },
          "clinic" : {
            "name" : "string",
            "address" : "string"
          }
          "doctor": {
            "name" : "string"
          },
          "appointment_date": 1671693012,
          "amount": "150.00"
      }     
    }
```

my code:

```
$data = Ticket::with('package')->with('user')->with('clinic')->with('doctor')->get();
    return response()->json([
        [
            'status'=>200, 
            'body'=> [
                'limit' => $request->limit,
                'offset' => $request->offset,
                'data' => $data
            ]
        ]
    ], 200);
```

Please help me, I feel stuck, thanks you!!!

Comment: why does the `doctor` not included in the query ?

Comment: sorry, i was missing and edited

Comment: Does your query working ?

Comment: yes, it doesn't take the specified data like the above json string

Answer (score 1):

You can add the column you want to get after the relationship name and separating them with `:` and if you want a multiple column you can separate them with `,`

```
$data = Ticket::with('package:id,name')->with('user:id,name')->with('clinic:id,name,address')->with('doctor:id,name')->get();
```

Take note that it will only work if you include the `primary key` of the table for it to work so the `json` will produce something like:

```
{
    "doctor": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Doctor Name"
    },
    "clinic": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "clinic name"
        "address": "clinic address"
    }
}
```

**Edit #1**

if you want to remove the id you can just modify the result using the [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources) but I don't know if it is a good idea.

create a new resource

```
php artisan make:resource TicketResource
```

then modify it to something like this :

```
public function toArray()
{
    return [
        ... // the ticket information
        "doctor" => [
            "name" => $this->doctor->name,
        ],
        "clinic" => [
            "name" => $this->clinic->name,
            "address" => $this->clinic->address,
        ],
    ];
}
```

then if you use it instead of return the `$data` you should pass the `$data` inside the `new TicketResource($data)`

```
$data = Ticket::with('package:id,name')->with('user:id,name')->with('clinic:id,name,address')->with('doctor:id,name')->get();

return response()->json([
        [
            'status'=>200, 
            'body'=> [
                'limit' => $request->limit,
                'offset' => $request->offset,
                'data' => new TicketResource($data)
            ]
        ]
    ], 200);
```

Comment: thank you, but is there any way without getting the id?

Comment: Well you can remove the id if you use the `eloquent resource` because you can modify the structure of the data

Comment: You can also use this syntax: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads. You can pass mutliple relationships into with([]) at once. To select certain column, you can use $query->select(['id', 'name']) inside a callback function. Finally you should use eloquent resources as @xenooooo said.